# SceneKit - Get camera default field of view

Tags: scenekit, perspectivecamera

How can I get the X and Y fields of view used by a SceneKit camera by default?
Per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNCamera_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNCamera/yFov), by default `camera.yFov` and `camera.xFov` are `0`, and SceneKit uses 60 degrees for `yFov` and automatically adjust `xFov`.

Any idea on how I can get the automatically set `xFov` ?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? How about

```
myCamera.xFov = 42.0
```

Comment: I don't want to set the fov, just to get it, like `camera = SCNCamera(); rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode); let fov = camera.xFov;` unfortunately this would return 0, not the fov used by default